# how to use TAP formatter module in Perl script & running the same on commandline

Tags: perl, command-line, tap, formatter

I have tried this syntax:

```
use TAP::Harness;
 my @tests = glob( 't/*.t' );
 my $harness = TAP::Harness->new({ formatter_class => 'TAP::Formatter::HTML',
                                   merge => 1 });
 $harness->runtests( @tests );
```

Then I executed the script as perl file.pl

Result:

> Can't load TAP::Formatter::HTML at file.pl line 32.
>
> 1..14
>
> #Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 14.

Then i tried the other method:

```
 prove -m -Q --formatter=TAP::Formatter::HTML >output.html
```

Result:

> No tests named and 't' directory not found at C:/Perl/lib/App/Prove.pm
> line 528.

Answer (score 1):

I too have not been able to get the `formatter_class` arg to work with `TAP::Formatter::HTML`.

However, the following should work with the `formatter` arg:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use TAP::Harness;
use TAP::Formatter::HTML;

my @tests = glob "t/*.t";

my $fmt = TAP::Formatter::HTML->new;    # Set up the formatter
   $fmt->output_file( 'results.html' ); # options in $fmt

my $harness = TAP::Harness->new( { formatter => $fmt } );

$harness->runtests( @tests );
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking

Comment: @user2314050 : `@tests` will contain the tests that you would like to run through the harness. There is an [excellent tutorial by Steve Purkis](http://www.slideshare.net/spurkis/tapharness-friends) of `TAP::Harness` that you should go through if you need to learn about the [Test Anything Protocol](http://testanything.org)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use TAP::Harness;

my @tests = glob( 't/*.t' );
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new();
$harness->runtests( @tests );
```

Check the documentation of `TAP::Harness`.

Its `man` page says:

> The constructor returns a new "TAP::Harness" object. It accepts an
>   optional hashref .

The list of the hashref whose keys are allowed in subroutine `new` can be found in its `man` page.

Check out its online documentattion [here](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Test-Harness-3.26/lib/Test/Harness.pm).

Comment: thanks for answering i think i might be missing something trivial in the entire process.. will have to check out

Comment: what is the role ".t" file in the execution of Tap formatter?

Comment: What should be put in "(@tests)" > $harness->runtests( @tests )

Comment: The OP's issue is related to using `T::F::HTML` as the formatter. Your answer doesn't capture that.